# Circular buffer of vectors

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I was getting a float from `stdin` once persecond and processing it. However, now I need to handle several space-separated values each second instead. As I am inexperienced with python, it is hard to select a suitable data structure.

- I need to compute mean of this data per channel. If the data is stored as `numpy.matrix`, this is straightforward.
- I also need to store a fixed number of points of history per channel. Up to now, a `collections.deque(maxlen=x)` was doing quite nicely.
- Lastly, I need to pass iterables for `y_axis` in `matplotlib.Axes.plot(x_axis, y_asis)` as many times as needed to draw all the signals. For example, if the data is stored as a deque of matrices, each second I would need to compose the into lists of values for each channel.

What data structure shall I use?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What's the issue that arises from several compared to one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your process seems to be slow, so you have time to info in deque. And just integrate the numpy world for the ease of mean and plot. It can look like :

[image: 10 buffers]

Run main() for an animation.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import collections as co
buffer=[]
for i in range(10):
    buffer.append(co.deque(maxlen=15))

def refresh(n):
    for t in range(10*n):
        x=np.random.rand()+t%10
        buffer[t%10].append(x)

refresh(15) # init  
buff=np.asarray(buffer)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
line = ax.plot(buff.T) 


def main():
    while True:
        refresh(1)
        buff=np.asarray(buffer) 
        print (buff.mean(axis=1))
        for i in range(10) :
            line[i].set_ydata(buff[i])
        fig.canvas.draw()
        for t in range(10**6):pass #tempo
```